# understanding pointers in functions (referring values)

Tags: c, pointers

```
int func (int a, int b, int *c);

int main()
{
int res, x, y, z;     //int res, x, y, *z;

printf("enter x \n");
scanf("%i", &x);
printf("enter y \n");
scanf("%i", &y);
res = func(x, y, &z);           //res = func(x, y, z);
printf("result  addition: %i, result multiplication %i \n", res, *z);
return 0;
}


int func (int a, int b, int *c)
{
int result;

result = a +b;
*c = a*b;        //(1)       alternative:d=a*b
                 //                      c=&d
return result; 
}
```

My problem is, that i don't understand, why this code doesn't work when i write it as i like i did in the comments (//) . Compiler warns me, that z is not initialised, but why isn't that a problem in the working version?

 
Another thing i don't understand is, why it's correct to refer pointer a value like i did it in (1) but it's wrong in the following code:

```
int main()
{
int a, *c, *d;

scanf("%i", &a);

*c=a;   //wrong
d=&a;   //correct
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a tip, but you should always put space between binary operators like multiplication.  You don't want to run into a bug and realize you actually dereferenced something just because the `*` got treated as the unary dereference operator.  Your code's simple so you don't have to worry about it now, but if it ever gets complex you could make a mistake.

Comment: when i see what people vote down and what people vote up here, it gives me headaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compiler warns me, that z is not initialised, but why isn't that a problem in the working version?**

The compiler warns you about z being uninitialized because you're passing it by value.  And what you're passing is an uninitialized value (which is basically garbage).
It doesn't warn you when you pass the address of z because there's nothing wrong with passing the address of a variable to a pointer.  The compiler doesn't check whether you're going to dereference c and use the uninitialized value of z.  The compiler's just not that "smart".  It assumes you'll do the right thing and just assign z a value by dereferencing c (which you indeed did).

**why it's correct to refer pointer a value like i did it in (1) but it's wrong in the following code**

As for your 2nd question, the first example works because the parameters of the functions get initialized to whatever values you called the function with. 
The 2nd example doesn't work because you're using uninitialized local variables.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where a variable is declared, it comes into existence at some memory location that can be retrieved with `&`, whereas (if you don't initialize it) the *contents* of that location is uninitialized. When `z` is an `int`, `&z` is a well-defined pointer because it is the address of a variable, not the contents of one. When `z` is an `int *`, `z`'s content is itself a pointer, but it's not initialized; hence the warning (and most likely, your program will crash when `scanf()` attempts to write to an arbitrary memory location).

Answer (score 0):

your question implies that you have no knowledge about pointers, I suggest you read about them first,

a pointer points to a variable, when you do

```
*c = a
```

you are trying to assign a value to the variable pointed to by c with the indirection operator '*',

the problem is that c is not pointing to anything in your code.

in the second one

```
d = &a;
```

you make the pointer d point to a. In other words you assign d the address of a. You really should read about pointers first otherwise, whatever we say here will not make sense to you.

Comment: My question was not, why *c=a is wrong and d=&a is correct, my question was, why it is correct in (1)

Comment: please read your own question, it is part of your question, in any case, it is obvious you have no idea about what pointers are, it is not bad to ask a question, but first read about them, it seems you don't even understand their purpose

Comment: also regarding your question about z, it doesn't work because in C you cannot permanently change the value of a variable through a function, UNLESS you change it through a pointer,

Comment: @Mcs Telling someone they "have no idea" about something they're trying to learn about is not going to make you friends.  Even if that's true, try to word it in a more supportive way :)

Comment: @ Kacy Raye Hello Kacy.  If you read what I said, I did tell him it is not bad to ask questions, but I think somebody should at least spend some time trying figure things out by himself. I don't think that is bad advice, he really has no idea:) And he can read and have some idea about it!